# Xcode warning when archiving project with Today Extension

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a Today Extension (Widget) which is building and running fine. When I archive for release, I am given two warnings in the build output:

```
Dsymutil Warning
warning: no debug symbols in executable (-arch armv7)

Dsymutil Warning
warning: no debug symbols in executable (-arch arm64)
```

I have most of the build settings for the target set to the iOS defaults so I'm not sure if I have done something wrong. Are extensions meant to ship with debug symbols? Willing to try different settings if someone could suggest any.